# ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' even when returning an observable

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, server-sent-events, ngzone

I found few questions with same title and, as far as I could see, some of them are suggesting that the solution is basically return an Observable instead of an array (others are about FireBase which isn't my case). Well, as far I am concern, the code below does return an Observable (look at "getServerSentEvent(): Observable {return Observable.create ...")

My final goal is get all events from a stream returned from a Rest WebFlux. I didn't past bellow the backend because I am pretty sure the issue is related to some mistake in Angular.

On top of that, I can debug and see the events properlly comming to extratos$ from app.component.ts(see image bellow).

Whole logs

```
core.js:6185 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:5743)
    at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:5920)
    at AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:5901)
    at AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:5879)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.js:36653)
    at AppComponent_Template (app.component.html:8)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11949)
    at refreshView (core.js:11796)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13229)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11527)
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SseService } from './sse.service';
import { Extrato } from './extrato';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [SseService],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  //extratos: any;
  extratos$ : Observable<any>;

  constructor(private appService: AppService, private sseService: SseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getExtratoStream();
  }

  getExtratoStream(): void {
    this.sseService
      .getServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8080/extrato")
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.extratos$ = data;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

sse.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Extrato } from './extrato';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SseService {
  extratos: Extrato[] = [];
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { }

  //getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<Array<Extrato>> {
  getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
          this.extratos.push(new Extrato(json['id'], json['descricao'], json['valor']));
          observer.next(this.extratos);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }

    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Extrato Stream</h1>
<div *ngFor="let ext of extratos$ | async">
  <div>{{ext.descricao}}</div>
</div>
```

Evidence that the observable extratos$ is filled in

[image]

Comment: `extratos$` is declared as `Array` and used as `Observable`?

Comment: as far as I see, I declare it as Observable in app.component.ts (extratos$ : Observable<any>;). Do you mean "extratos: Extrato[] = [];" from sse.services.ts? I guess it isn't the issue. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this `observer.next(this.extratos);`, that means `this.extratos` is what you get on component side in the `data` argument of the callback, so when you do this `this.extratos$ = data;` you are actually storing the `extratos` `Array`. TypeScript doesn't complain about it, probably because it's not smart enough to infer the types when you build an `Observable` from scratch like you did.

Try this:

```
this.extratos$ = this.sseService
      .getServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8080/extrato");
```

and in the template: `<div *ngFor="let ext of extratos$ | async">`

Comment: Now it is working but please let me double check: are sure I am still coding as it is supposed when working with Async approach? I have read numerous blogs and articles all mentioning to use "| async". Do you see some other weird code above that I should do different in order to properly set async on ngfor or, maybe, I missed some point that "async" isn't necessary at all?

Comment: Forget my previous answer I just understood that you're using SSE, which makes your Observable a hot Observable and this is indeed a use case for the `AsyncPipe`. I've edited my answer

Comment: It is working what it is good. But, regard my knowledge it reveals some gap: how can your suggestion missing "subscribe" works? In order to get the result from an observable it is a MUST to subscribe, right?

Comment: Yes but the `AsyncPipe` does it for you, which is good because it also unsubscribes for you, which you can forget as a developer when you subscribe yourself, and this can cause memory leaks

Comment: You certaling answered my question. A last comment if you don't mind:  "| async" means "subscribe, only start to listen when there is the first event and listen until it is closed" and "$" at the end of extratos is just a conventional way to say "this is an observable", i.e., it doesn't add nothing else then a friendly conventional name, right?

Comment: Exactly, it also means unsubscribe when the component is destroyed

Comment: And yes the $ is just a convention